# How can I transfer a collection of float values to a node socket​​?

Tags: python, node-editor, pynodes

How can I transfer a collection of float values to a node socket​​?

This is what I've tried:

- Create a list of float values ​​and convert each of them to a string
- Pass the string to the socket
- In the right place in the script, I will retrieve the float values by accessing the string values from within an eval() function:

`list_x = eval(self.inputs['Points'].VectorProperty.x)`

`list_y = eval(self.inputs['Points'].VectorProperty.y)`

`list_point = list(zip(list_x, list_y))`

I understand that this is not correct. But what is the correct way to do this?

[image: code]

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using a float vector as is?

Answer (score 1):

In the case you are describing you can use the NodeSocketVector a socket. It is a built in NodeSocket.

```
class MyNode(Node):
    def init(self):
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketVector', name="Vector")

    def get_output_vector_value(self):
        return self.inputs[0].default_value
```